# The Eclipse launcher is giving me an error message

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to set up my machine to do some Android development, but I'm running into a couple of issues when installing everything I need. Here's some info about my set up:

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit
I have the Java JDK 1.6.0_22 version installed
I downloaded Eclipse Galileo 3.5 R2 for Java Developers

My first issue is that because the Android SDK doesn't work with Eclipse 3.6 yet I had to download 3.5 instead. I can see a 64 bit Java Developers version on the main download page, but I can only see the 32 bit for Galileo:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2

However the classic edition does have a Windows 64 bit option. The Android SDK documentation recommends using the Java Development edition, so I decided to give the 32 bit Java version a try. Unfortunately the Eclipse launcher gives me an error about the JVM terminated with exit code -1.

I tried searching for solutions, but didn't come up with anything useful. Should I go ahead and use the classic version of Eclipse or try to get the 32 bit version to work? Is there a 64 bit version of Galileo for Java Developers available somewhere? I think my computer set up is fairly common so I feel like I'm running into these issues because I misunderstood the set up process.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, match bit sizes.  While it *shouldn't* matter given that the IDE will be in a separate process from the emulator (and it simply doesn't apply if you're debugging on a device), do it anyway, just for paranoia's sake.  And here's a [64-bit classic download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.2-201002111343/eclipse-SDK-3.5.2-win32-x86_64.zip) link, just 'cause I'm helpful like that.

And speaking of helpful, the next issue you'll run into is with "protocol bind unable to connect to socket: NNNN".  The issue is that Windows Vista & Windows 7 specify "localhost" as an IPv6 address, :::1 I believe (nope!  ::1) , but Android doesn't speak IPv6 so well just yet, so the debugger can't connect to the emulator or an Actual Device.

Easy fix on the google end of things:  Just connect to 127.0.0.1 when trying to establish a debug session.  C'mon folks!

Until someone patches adb or improves Android's IPv6 handling you'll need to edit your `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.  It should contain a line something like `::1 localhost`.  Just replace `::1` with `127.0.0.1`.  And you'll need to give admin permissions in order to save changes (or maybe saveAs, delete the original, and rename... I ran into something goofy like that recently and suspect this was it).

And if you have an HTC device, you need to download their [HTC Sync](http://www.htc.com/us/support) app in order to get the correct USB drivers to do an dev work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember my exact configuration, but I'm pretty sure I had to "downgrade" everything to 32bit versions, eclipse, java (and python for app engine /pyglet stuff). You will definitely have less issues when using the 32bit stuff that's for sure.

Comment: That's a bit annoying but at least I'm glad it's not just me with these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse Galileo on Windows 7 64-bit without issues. Thsi is the version of Eclipse I'm using: Version: 3.5.2
Build id: M20100211-1343